# Knockoutjs view locator?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I was wondering if there is any way to define an area(div tag?) in my html, where the template changes depending on what object it is bound to?

Let's say we would have a

- ShellView / ShellViewModel
- ListView / ListViewModel
- EditOneView / EditOneViewModel

And the ShellViewModel has a variable that's either a ListViewModel or a EditOneViewModel, and depending on that variable the ListView or the EditOneView would be used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can pass a function to the name property in your template binding that will choose which function to use:

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: whichTemplate }'></div>

var ShellViewModel = {
    //....

    whichTemplate: function(object) {
        // test which class you are using and return the name of the appropriate template
    }
}
```